# How to handle QTableView long press?

Tags: qt, user-interface, embedded, signals-slots

I am developing embedded application for device with touch screen and need to handle separately single clicks and long presses on QTableView items. Single clicks should open editing dialog, long presses should only select item. The problem is that there is only 'pressed' signal in Qt, and I don't know what is the right way to handle long presses. Could anybody suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using QTableView directly, subclass it and then implement the virtual functions: -

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
```

You can then decide how you want to handle the events, creating a timer to see if a certain time has passed before the release event.

Answer (score 1):

Install an event filter on the view's `viewport()` widget and process its mouse events. Use `view->indexAt()` to find out which item was clicked. See also [Event Filters](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters).